# Can a virtual method abort the execution of the abstract method overriding it?

Tags: c#, overriding, state-machine

I am implementing a state machine for game AI, and one of the states —`EatState`— must be accessible from almost every other state and have priority over the rest. Instead of defining this transition in all the states, I was thinking of implementing it in a superclass `BaseState` from which all the other extend.

`BaseState` has 4 abstract methods that the subclasses override, which are

1. Enter()
2. UpdateLogic() -> check for the conditions to transitionate from one state to another...
3. UpdatePhysics() -> apply movement and others
4. Exit()

The problem I find if I implement the check for the transition to the `EatState` in the superclass, and then call the particular checks of the subclass, is that the latter results *override* the ones obtained in the superclass:

```
public class BaseState {
   public virtual void UpdateLogic() {
      // Let's imagine the condition is met and the state is changed
      if (someCondition){
         changeState("EatState");
      }
   }
}


public class MoveState : BaseState {
   public override void UpdateLogic() {
      base.UpdateLogic();
      // But here the condition is also met, so the state is re-changed.
      if (someOtherCondition){
         changeState("FightState");
      }
   }
}
```

I realise that I can just move the prioritary state check to the bottom of the method in order to override the result of the subclass:

```
public class MoveState : BaseState {
   public override void UpdateLogic() {
      if (someOtherCondition){
         changeState("FightState");
      }
      base.UpdateLogic();
   }
}
```

or that I could make the check in the subclass more restrictive, but this question kept me wondering about this:

Is there a way to avoid the execution of an override method once the base virtual method is being executed in the superclass? I am looking for something that would act like a `return` statement that could somehow propagate from the superclass to the subclass and abort the latter execution.

Comment: Perhaps have a non-overridable base method and have that call a protected virtual method in the derived classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control this behavior by returning bool instead of void to indicate if the base class behavior was used.

```
public class BaseState
{
    public virtual bool UpdateLogic()
    {
        // Let's imagine the condition is met and the state is changed
        if (someCondition)
        {
            changeState("EatState");
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}

public class MoveState : BaseState
{
    public override bool UpdateLogic()
    {
        var wasUpdatedInBase = base.UpdateLogic();
        // But here the condition is also met, so the state is re-changed.
        if (!wasUpdatedInBase && someOtherCondition)
        {
            changeState("FightState");
        }
    }
}
```